# Prove: If $x+y>22$ then $x>11$ and $ y>11$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove: If $x+y>22$ then $x>11$ and $ y>11$

I'm not sure but I believe you have to use proof by contradiction.

EDIT: 
Proof: By contradiction, let $x+y>22$ and $x \leq 11$ or $y \leq 11$. Adding both sides, we get $x+y \leq 22$ which is a contradiction since we said $x+y>22$.

Any corrections?

Comment: What about $x=3$, $y=20$?  Or do you want an"or" instead of "and?"

Comment: You mean $x>11$ or $y>11$?

Comment: Did you mean $x\gt11$ **OR** $y\gt11$

Comment: ok let me edit.

Comment: As per Paul's comment, your proof **must** be wrong, due to the fact that the conditional in the title and in the first line of the question is *false*.

Comment: I haven't downvoted this question, but I wonder: Is it expected on Math SE to explain downvotes on questions, or only on answers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot add two equations joined by a logical or. The original statement is false so there is nothing to prove. If you replace the and in the original statement with or, then the or in your proof becomes an and, making the proof valid.

Comment: What do you mean by the original statement is false?

Comment: I mean that the statement "if $x+y>22$ then $x>11$ and $y>11$" is logically false, as has been amply illustrated by commenters.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if $x<11$ **AND** $y<11$ you can sum it into $x+y<22$, but if its **OR** you have a complex, not a system, you can't sum it(even it would be eqs).
For example, x=13 or y=2 doesn't mean x+y=15.